# Error when using defined Endpoint in WSO2 ESB from registry

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry, wso2-esb

I have created an endpoint using WSO2 GREG and then added it to ESB ProxyService from registry but trying this service gave me this error:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2015-10-21 08:12:49,178]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: /services/TestProxyReg, MessageID: urn:uuid:a1c1994a-56b9-44e2-b567-f290a3411275, Direction: request, MESSAGE = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = Invalid endpoint configuration., Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
   name="TestProxyReg"
   transports="https,http"
   statistics="disable"
   trace="disable"
   startOnLoad="true">
   <target endpoint="gov:/trunk/endpoints/ep-myUrl.wso2.services-test-testEndpoint">
      <outSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="text" value="A test"/>
         </log>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

What is wrong here?

**Edit:**

One additional thing: I noticed that endpoints created in G-Reg are not the same as in ESB server, for example:

In G-Reg:

```
<metadata xmlns="http://www.wso2.org/governance/metadata">
  <overview>
  <name>testEndpoint</name>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <address>https://localhost:8245/services/test</address>
  </overview>
</metadata>
```

In ESB:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="gov/testEndpointA">
   <address uri="localhost:9443/services/Persons_DataService/select_all_Persons_operation">
      <suspendOnFailure>
         <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
      </suspendOnFailure>
      <markForSuspension>
         <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
         <retryDelay>0</retryDelay>
      </markForSuspension>
   </address>
</endpoint>
```

So I think I know why there is an error like this - I should have created Endpoint that I need via ESB, not using G-Reg?

Comment: Have you shared the registry between G-REG and ESB?

Comment: Yes, I see the special link when browsing registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the endpoint using WSO2 ESB management console and save it in the governance registry. you can follow the [official doc.](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Adding+an+Endpoint) According to the document create the endpoint and as the final step save it in registry (click save in registry).

Then refer that endpoint to you proxy service.